# Controlling Gemfire cache updates in the background

Tags: gemfire

I will be implementing a Java program that acts as a gemfire client. The program will continuosly process records that it receives on its port from a remote program. Each record will be processed using the static data cached with my program. The cache may get updated behind the scenes in my program when it is changed on the gemfire server. The processing of one record may take a few seconds. I run the risk of processing half the record with static data that was prevalent before the change and rest of the record with static data that has taken effect after the change. Is there a way I can tell gemfire to not apply the cache to the local client until I am done processing the ongoing record?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach: Use a Continuous query "Select *" instead of event registration. A CQ does not update the client region like a subscription does. Make your client region LOCAL. After receiving the CQ event on the client, execute your long running process and put the value that you received from the CQ into your client region.  Decoupling client and server in this way will allow your client to run long-running processes.

Alternatively: if you must have the client cache proxied with the server as an absolute requirement, then keep the interest registration AND register a CQ. Ignore the event callback from the subscription but handle your long-running process using the event callback from the CQ.

The following is from page 683 at http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/pdf/pivotal-gemfire-ug.pdf

CQs do not update the client region. This is in contrast to other server-to-client messaging like the updates sent to satisfy interest registration and responses to get requests from the client's Pool.